# The Riemann Integrability of Step Functions and the Riemann-Stieltjes Integrability of a Step Function w.r.t. Another

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Here is Definition 6.14 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> The *unit step function* $I$ is defined by 
>   $$ I(x) = \begin{cases}\  0 \ & \qquad  ( \ x \leq 0 \ ), \\ \ 1 \ & \qquad  (\ x > 0 \ ). \end{cases}  \tag{A} $$

Here is my question:

> Now let $a, b, c, d$ be any real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c, d \in [a, b]$. Let the functions $f$ and $\alpha$ be defined on $[a, b]$ by $$ f(x) = I(x-c), \qquad \alpha(x) = I(x-d). $$ 
>   Then does $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$? And if so, then how to find  $ \int_a^b f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha$?

Here is the link to one of my Math SE posts where I've copied the relevant definitions from Baby Rudin (i.e. Definitions 6.1 and 6.2):

[Theorem 6.10 in Baby Rudin: If $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$ with only finitely many points of discontinuity at which $\alpha$ is continuous, then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319741/theorem-6-10-in-baby-rudin-if-f-is-bounded-on-a-b-with-only-finitely-man)

My Attempt:

> First we assume that $c \neq d$. Then $f$ has only finitely many (i.e. at most one) points of discontinuity at which $\alpha$ is continuous, and so by Theorem 6.10 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition,  $f$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on  $[a, b]$.
>
> Now if $a < d < b$, then by Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin, we have 
>   $$ \int_a^b f \ \mathrm{d} \alpha = f(d) = \begin{cases} \ 0 & \qquad ( \ d \leq c \ ), \\ \ 1 & \qquad ( \ d > c \ ). \end{cases}  \tag{0} $$ 
>   This holds irrespective of whether $c = d$ or $c \neq d$.

Here is the link to my Math SE post on Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin: If $a<s<b$, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$, then . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329858/theorem-6-15-in-baby-rudin-if-asb-f-is-bounded-on-a-b-f-is-contin)

> If $d  = a$ or $d = b$, then $\alpha$ is constant on all of $[a, b] - \{ \ d \ \}$.
>
> Let us suppose that $a < c < b$ and $d = a$. Then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ by Theorem 6.10 in Baby Rudin.
>
> Let $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $n \geq 4$ and such that $x_1 < c$.
>
> Then $$ U(P, f, \alpha ) = f \left( x_1 \right) = 0, \qquad L(P, f, \alpha) = f\left( x_0 \right) = 0. $$ 
>   And $$ L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \int_a^b f \ \mathscr{d} \alpha \leq  U(P, f, \alpha), $$ 
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f \ \mathscr{d} \alpha = 0 \tag{1} $$ 
>   when $a < c < b$ and $d = a$. 
>   Now  let us suppose that $a < c < b$ and $d = b$. Then again by Theorem 6.10 in Baby Rudin we can conclude that $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$.
>
> Then for any partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ we note that $$U(P, f, \alpha) = 0 = L(P, f, \alpha), $$
>   from which it follows that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f \ \mathscr{d} \alpha = 0 \tag{2} $$ 
>   when $a < c < b$ and $d = b$.
>
> If $c = d = b$, then $\alpha$ is the zero function on $[a, b]$ and so 
>   $$ \int_a^b f \ \mathscr{d} \alpha = 0. \tag{3} $$
>
> Now let us suppose that $c = d = a$. Let $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be any partition of $[a, b]$. Then 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) = f\left( x_1 \right) = 1,$$
>   and 
>   $$ L(P, f, \alpha) = f\left( x_0 \right) = 0;$$
>   so that 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) = 1 > \varepsilon $$
>   for any real number $\varepsilon$ such that $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. Therefore by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin $f \not\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$.
>
> Thus from (A), (0), (1), (2), and (3) put together we can write 
>   $$ \int_a^b I(x-c) \ \mathrm{d} I(x-d) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } a < d < b \ \mbox{ and } d \leq c, \\
> 1 \ & \ \mbox{ if } a < d < b \ \mbox{ and } d > c, \\
> 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } c = d = b, \\ 
> 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } a < c < b \ \mbox{ and } d \in \{ \  a, b \ \}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   and this integral does not exist when $c = d = a$.

Is what I've done so far correct?

> Now let us find $\int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x$.
>
> If $c= b$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, and so 
>   $$ \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 0 \tag{4} $$
>   in this case.
>
> If $c= a$, then $f(a) = 0 $ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [a, b] -  \{\ a \ \}$. Let the function $g$ on $[a, b]$ be defined by 
>   $$ g(x) = 1- f(x). $$
>   Then $g$ satisfies the conditions of Prob. 1, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin. So 
>   $$ \int_a^b g(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 0. $$

Here is the link to my Math SE post on Prob. 1, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Prob. 1, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x \neq x_0$, then $\int f\ \mathrm{d}\alpha=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372386/prob-1-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-fx-0-1-and-fx-0-for-all-x-neq-x-0)

> But 
>   $$ \int_a^b g(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = \int_a^b \left( 1 - f(x) \right)  \ \mathrm{d} x = \int_a^b 1 \ \mathrm{d} x - \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x =  b-a \ - \ \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x. $$ 
>   So we can conclude that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = b-a \tag{5} $$
>   if $c = a$.
>
> Now let's assume that $a < c < b$.
>
> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Let $n > 2$, and let  $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $\Delta x_i < \varepsilon$ and such that  $c$ is one of the points of $P$; suppose $x_j  = c$ for some $j = 1, \ldots, n-1$.
>
> Then 
>   $$ U(P, f) = \Delta x_{j+1} + \cdots + \Delta x_n = x_n - x_j = b-c,$$ 
>   and 
>   $$ L(P, f) = \Delta x_{j+2} + \Delta x_n = x_n - x_{j+1} = b- x_{j+1} . $$ 
>   So 
>   $$ U(P, f) - L(P, f) = \Delta x_{j+1} < \varepsilon.  $$
>   Thus $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$ by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin.
>
> Furthermore, for any partition $Q$ of $[a, b]$ we have 
>   $$ L(Q, f) \leq \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \leq U(Q, f). $$
>   So for $P$, we can write 
>   $$ b - x_{j+1}  \leq \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \leq b- c, $$
>   which upon letting $x_{j+1} \to c+$ gives
>   $$ \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = b-c \tag{6}  $$
>   if $a < c < b$.
>
> From (A), (4), (5), and (6) together we can conclude that 
>   $$  \int_a^b I(x-c) \ \mathrm{d} x = b-c 
> $$
>   for all $c \in [a, b]$.

Is this calculation correct? If so, then have I correctly used the relevant facts?

Have I again written out too lengthy a post? I mean can all these calculations be performed in a more efficient and yet elementary enough way?

P.S.:

> After reading one of the comments below, I must mention that (0) above holds only for those $c, d \in [a, b]$ such that $a < d < b$ and $c \neq d$.
>
> So we need to discuss the case $a < c = d < b$ separately. Now $n$ be a natural number $> 2$. let $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be a partition of $[a, b]$ such that $c$ is one of the points of $P$; suppose that $x_{j=1} = c$ for some $j \in \{ \ 2, \ldots, n \ \}$. Then we note that 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) = 1, \ \mbox{ and } \ L(P, f, \alpha) = 0, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) = 1-0 > \varepsilon $$
>   for any real number $\varepsilon$ such that $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. Thus by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin we can conclude that $f \not\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ in this case.
>
> Thus 
>   $$ \int_a^b I(x-c) \ \mathrm{d} I(x-d) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } a < d < b \ \mbox{ and } d < c, \\
> 1 \ & \ \mbox{ if } a < d < b \ \mbox{ and } d > c, \\
> 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } c = d = b, \\ 
> 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } a < c < b \ \mbox{ and } d \in \{ \  a, b \ \}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   and this integral does not exist when $c = d = a$ or when $a < c=d < b$.

Comment: Going through your previous questions, I noticed that you did not get a  response to those questions which are too lengthy. Maybe you could make the question a little concisely to ensure response. Just an advice.

Comment: @SahibaArora yes, you're right. I write these proofs this way in order to ensure that most details are filled in. Otherwise some book or the other (or a third or a fourth) will definitely have these proofs.

Comment: @SahibaArora have you found this post too be too lengthy too?

Comment: I don't think you used Thm. 6.15 appropriately in your display (0) (for the case $c=d$). The condition for 6.15 is that $f$ is continuous at $d$, but $f$ is discontinuous at $c=d$. So care shall be taken.

Comment: In fact in ex. 6.2, you have already proven that $f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ iff $f(d)=f(d+)$ so your result shall be wrong.

Comment: You might be interested in reading this too: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~safon002/Archive/Math5616H/NOTES/B.pdf

Comment: @LiChunMin yes, you're right. This is what makes this Math SE forum so indispensable! And, this is why I prefer to write out my proofs with all the details. How else would people like you point out the errors in my reasoning? How else would I know that I've erred in my logic?

Comment: @LiChunMin can you please read through my post now? I've added a P.S.